# Netlogo, iterating n items, in a list of length x (where n <= x)

Tags: netlogo

I am wondering whether if its possible to iterate over n item using for loop (foreach), where the list is of length x.
For example, for a list of length 6 (x), I want to iterate the first 4 items (n) and add them to another list B.

lets say list-A is [ 7 8 12 11 5 6]
 output required: list-B should be [7 8 12 11]

The code below adds all the items from list A to list B, since iteration goes through the entire list. I want to stop it at the 4th iteration. so only the first 4 items will be added.

```
set list-A [ 7 8 12 11 5 6]
set list-B []
let n 4

foreach list-A [
i ->
set list-B lput i list-B
]
```

Answer (score 3):

NetLogo has `sublist` to extract one list from the middle of another. In your case it would look like:

```
to testme
  let list-A [ 7 8 12 11 5 6]
  let list-B sublist list-A 0 4
  print list-B
end
```